# Solr Suggester weightField removing fractional part in result for float type field

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud, autosuggest

I have setup Solr 9 for auto suggestion. There is a custom score field based on which I am going to rank suggestion. I am also returning weightField that is pfloat type. When this field is return in suggestion, its fractional part is removed that is bit confusing. Where is the issue

**This is what is shown in Solr admin**

[image]

**This is what I am seeing in Solr suggest output**

[image]